# Difference between two dates with decimal result

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007

I want to get the difference between two dates, but I want the result to be in decimal numbers, for example if the difference is (1 Year and 6 Months) I want the result to be (1.5) which means Year and a half!

Answer (score 1):

There is a specific function which does this in excel - YEARFRAC function - it calculates slightly differently according to the 3rd argument, see excel help for more but this is the basic version

> =YEARFRAC(A2,B2,1)

Where A2 is the start date and B2 the end date. This is accurate to the day, I assume that's what you want